# Complex De Moivre's theorem question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Express this in terms of multiple angles.

$\cos^3x \sin^4x$

I've used the relationships $$\cos(nx) = \frac{z^n+z^{-n}}{2}$$

$$\sin(nx) = \frac{z^n-z^{-n}}{2j}$$

And end up with $$\cos^3x \sin^4x = \frac{(z^3+3z+3z^{-1}+z^{-3})(z^4-4z^2+6-4z^{-2}+z^{-4})}{2^7}$$

but is there a way to do this question without this expansion?If not is there a quick way of performing the expansion? My head hurts considering it.

Thanks

Comment: Wrong identities...

$$cos(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}+e^{-inx}}{2}$$

$$sin(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}$$

Comment: @b00nheT Im aware of those too but what is wrong with these? My textbook uses these throughout the complex numbers chapter?

Comment: There is nothing wrong if $z=e^{ix} \quad \ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

Formulae used:
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Double-angle\ formula}&:\qquad\cos 2A=1-2\sin^2 A\\
\\
\mathrm{Factor\ formula}&:\qquad \frac{\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)}{2}=\sin A\sin B\\
\\
\mathrm{Factor\ formula}&:\qquad \frac{\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)}{2}=\cos A\cos B\\
\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\cos^3x\sin^4 x&=\left(\sin x \cos x\right)^3\cdot \sin x\\
&=\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{2}\right)^3 \cdot \sin x\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\cdot \sin^22x\cdot\sin 2x\ \sin x\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1-\cos 4x}{2}\cdot \frac{\cos x-\cos 3x}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{32}\left(\cos x-\cos 3x-\cos x \cos 4x+\cos 3x\cos 4x\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{32}\left(\cos x-\cos 3x-\left(\frac{\cos 5x +\cos3x}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{\cos 7x+\cos x}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{32}\left({3\over2}\cos x-{3\over 2}\cos 3x-\frac{\cos 5x }{2}+\frac{\cos 7x}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{64}\left(3\cos x-3\cos 3x-\cos 5x+\cos 7x\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$